# QML - Retrieving index of delegate in DelegateModel

Tags: qt, listview, delegates, qml

I have trouble retrieving the **index** of a delegate that is instantiated inside a **DelegateModel** for a **ListView**.
The minimal example as following:

LastProcedures.qml

```
ListModel {
ListElement {
    procedure: "Liver Resection"
    surgeon: "Prof. Dr. Joyride"
    recent: true
    }
    ...
}
```

main.qml

```
ListView {
        id: list_lastProcedures
        model: displayDelegateModel
    }
DelegateModel {
    id: displayDelegateModel
    delegate: lastProceduresDelegate
    model: LastProcedures {}
    groups: [
                DelegateModelGroup {
                    includeByDefault: false
                    name: "recent"
                }
            ]
    filterOnGroup: "recent"
    Component.onCompleted: {
        var rowCount = model.count;
        items.remove(0,rowCount);
        for( var i = 0;i < rowCount;i++ ) {
            var entry = model.get(i);
                // Only the recent three
                if((entry.recent == true) && (items.count < 3)) {
                    items.insert(entry, "recent");
                }
            }
        }
    }
Component {
    id: lastProceduresDelegate
    Text{
        text: model.index
    }
}
```

The text index prints always -1. Without a DelegateModel it prints the index in the ListView. How can I access the correct index of the delegate in the Listview?

Comment: Did you try simply `index` instead of `model.index`?

Comment: @Silex: `index` is just a shorthand for `model.index` isn't it? 
But, if you remove your filter function, and turn the `filterOnGroup` of, you get the right `model.index`. But I don't understand your function anyway. [Maybe this helps you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39770958/how-to-add-elements-to-a-delegatemodelgroup-depending-on-a-property). But if you only want filtering and/or sorting, you might want to use a `QSortFilterProxyModel` which is way more performing. It's basic functions is easily exposed. A nice QML FilterModel is this: https://github.com/oKcerG/SortFilterProxyModel/

Comment: model.index and index are equivalent. Since I'll have a c++ model later on I wanted to create a prototype with some dummy data just in QML. But it seems like I have to jump into QSortFilterProxyModel right away.
@derM Your link was already a base for this implementation. The function just empties the "items" and adds the relevant entries to the "recent" group. It works well but I can't get an index for the entries in this group.

Comment: [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#qml-data-models) the documentations writes: "A special index role containing the index of the item in the model is also available to the delegate. Note this index is set to -1 if the item is removed from the model."
So is the removing from items the problem? And is there no index set after inserting again?

Comment: I thought the removal at the beginning might be the problem, as well. But commenting out that specific line, does not help.

Answer (score 4):

you can use "lastProceduresDelegate.DelegateModel.itemsIndex" instead of "model.index"

just like this:

```
Component {
    id: lastProceduresDelegate
    Text{
        text: lastProceduresDelegate.DelegateModel.itemsIndex
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with not removing all entries and adding them back to groups, but instead just remove unwanted entries. This ways the index stays valid. 
If someone could explain this behavior further, that would be nice.

```
DelegateModel {
    id: displayDelegateModel
    delegate: lastProceduresDelegate
    model: LastProcedures {}
    groups: [
                DelegateModelGroup {
                    includeByDefault: true
                    name: "recenttrue"
                }
            ]
    filterOnGroup: "recenttrue"
    Component.onCompleted: {
        for( var i = 0;i < items.count;i++ ) {
            var entry = items.get(i).model;
            // Only the recent
            if((entry.recent != true)) {
                items.removeGroups(i, 1, "recenttrue");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DelegateModel` has some hidden magic regarding groups (it's not very visible but it's [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-delegatemodel.html#groups-prop) ). For each group you create, the `DelegateModel` attached property will receive two new properties: `<group>Index` and `in<Group>`.

In your case this means you will get the following properties: `recentIndex` and `inRecent` (or in your own answer: `recenttrueIndex` and `inRecenttrue`).

I think with what you want to do you should go the `recenttrue` route and draft the `Component` as follows:

```
Component {
    id: lastProceduresDelegate
    Text {
        text: lastProceduresDelegate.DelegateModel.recenttrueIndex
    }
}
```