# Qml How to match ListView data

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a data set like the picture. I want to remove the row for which the data of column 2 is "b1".
How can I get the row index, or how can I get the model index of the entry?

[image]

Comment: If you want to automatically filter and remove that row, the `ListView` is the wrong place to start. You should do that on the model level. Please be more specific on your use case, about: **When** do you want to remove the row? **How** do you want to remove the row (only from the view or also from the model? **How** will the row be selected for deletion? And share some code where you try it, so we can play a little, to find a fitting solution together with you.

Comment: If you are only interested in filtering it from the view, but keeping it in the data, you can consider a either a `QSortFilterModel` or a `DelegateModel`

Comment: I create a function want to find which row I want delete, just delete from the view

Comment: but how can i get DetegateModel data

Comment: Maybe this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39770958/how-to-add-elements-to-a-delegatemodelgroup-depending-on-a-property

Comment: @derM ,thank you very much, I used **DelegateModelGroup** do it